# Joomla: Automatically add articles in a category/section as submenus

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I have a section in Joomla called **About**.
Under the About section I have categories **One**, **Two** and **Three**.

In my Main Menu I have about as a link which shows a component showing all the categories and articles.

I want to have all the categories made as submenus of the section and then further all the articles as submenus of their categories.

It is obviously possible to do this manually. However, I would like new articles to automatically be added to the menu. (Mainly because I want to allow a user to add articles from the front-end.) Is there any way to do this, either with the built in Joomla functionality or with a plugin, module or component?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [JA T3 Template Framework V2](http://wiki.joomlart.com/wiki/JA_Template_Framework/Overview) and it's Mega Menu let you list modules on your menu and they will appear as menu items. I use latest articles modules to achieve what you're asking for. It's easy to do just install the template framework and follow the steps posted on the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

I never seen plugins/components/modules that added menus as said, but there are several solutions (specifically modules) that list the categories inside a section like a menu, in the frontend.